# Calling files from root directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a script that needs to use a json file from separate folder, is there a way to access the location without directly calling the path?  Is it possible to use  something like`..\\subfolder1\\myjsonfile` ?  I need to access the json file from my script1.py in my subfolder2.  Thanks!

```
.
  subfolder1
    myjsonfile.json
  subfolder2
    script1.py
    script2.py
main.py
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, if you're using a standard `open()` or similar, where you give it the filepath, you can just do `open('../subfolder1/myjsonfile')`, and it'll work fine. Have you actually tried this? Are you getting a particular error, and if so can you edit your post to include it?

Comment: Sorry, to add more clarity in my question, is there any way I can make sure that I can access that path even when parent directory is located somewhere else?

Comment: Relative paths (those that don't start with `/` or `~`) take 'whatever file is currently being run' as their location. A relative path like `../subfolder/myjsonfile` will work no matter where the location of the parent folder is, as long as `subfolder1` and `subfolder2` are siblings underneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple process to get the absolute path instead of relative, and then adding the required subdirectory to it.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
pwd = Path(__file__).parent.parent.absolute()
filepath = os.path.join(pwd, 'subfolder1/myjsonfile.json')
# process filepath as you want
```

Comment: sorry, I am getting the error ```name '__file__' is not defined```

Comment: How are you running this program/script?

Comment: It doesn't work when I try calling it directly in the script (in "script1.py"), but works when I call entire script through the terminal (when I execute "main.py")

Comment: This approach works when the file is called via the terminal. Is it a requirement for it to work in IDLE?

Comment: It happens since Python Shell doesn't detect current file path in ```__file__```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to get the current working directory and then the parent:

```
import os
import pathlib
cwd = os.getcwd()
p = pathlib.Path(cwd).parent
```